# Ajax call never gets executed

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I got a simple php page that executes a Jquery script as follows:

SCRIPT part:

```
    <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
          $(".ajax_link").mouseover(function(){
               sfpRx($(this).text());
          });
     }

    function sfpRx(sfp){
        console.log("sfpRx Was executed");
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/NOKIA/sfp-load.php?sfp="+sfp,
            async: true,
            dataType: "text",
            timeout: 5,
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
```

HTML part:

```
<td class="ajax_link">3FE62600AA</td>
```

sfp-load.php content:

```
<?php echo $_GET['sfp'];?>
```

*Explanation*: everytime I mouse over the HTML part on the page, it executes the **sfpRx()** function that makes an ajax call to **sfp-load.php**. This Php page should return "**3FE62600AA**" to the ajax call, which should get printed in the console.

*Problem*: the "**3FE62600AA**" never gets printed in the console but I'm certain that the **sfpRx()** function is called because it prints "**sfpRx Was executed**" in the console. What could be happening? Am i forgetting anything? I'am sure the sfp-load.php page is in the NOKIA/ folder. I'am really annoyed with this.

Comment: Even though the function was called, the AJAX might have failed or the PHP might have failed. [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: Yes, the developers tool's request/response shows every request that I make to the php page every time I pass the mouse over the html tag. The Jquery liberaries are all included. No errors in console. I'am running on a server

Comment: It shows every request, what is the response for each?

Comment: response is blank

Comment: Then something is wrong with your PHP. Check your error logs.

Comment: Just tryied to access the php page directly with the link: http://10.200.6.253/NOKIA/sfp-load.php?sfp=3FE62600AA and it returns me 3FE62600AA. The php is OK.

Comment: Inside your sfpRx, Can you console.log(sfp) to make sure sfp is returning the text you want and not blank.

Comment: I edited this line : console.log("sfpRx Was executed"); to console.log(sfp); and YES, the sfpRx() is getting the 3FE62600AA text correctly

Comment: Can you post the PHP receiving the request?

Comment: http://prnt.sc/e5qyga

Comment: *Smacks forehead* Take `timeout: 5,` out of your AJAX call. 5 milliseconds is not enough time for a response.

Comment: Did that fix the issue?

Comment: Thank you man. That was the issue. The Unblessed timeout messing it all up!